# Sort array of strings based on priority substring at the end of the string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, delimited, custom-sort

How can I order an array from this:

```
$unordered_array = ['11196311|3','17699636|13','11196111|0','156875|2','17699679|6','11196237|7','3464760|10'];
```

To this

```
$ordered_array = ['11196111', '156875', '11196311', '17699679','11196237','3464760', '17699636'];
```

The number after the "|" defines the position, and the array needs to be ordered from lower to higher, and remove the position number in the final array.

Comment: Use `usort()`. The comparison function extracts the number after `|` and compares them.

Comment: You can remove the position number after you sort the array, using `array_map`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = array();
foreach($unordered_array as $value) {
    $value = explode('|', $value);
    $array [$value[1]]= $value[0];    
}
ksort($array);
$ordered_array = array_values($array);

var_dump($ordered_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the values into two arrays containing the ids and the ordering priorities, then sort the ids array using the priorities array.  The following approach will even work when the same priority number is assigned to more than one id.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/q0AsV))

```
$unordered_array = ['11196311|3','17699636|13','11196111|0','156875|2','17699679|6','11196237|7','3464760|10'];

$ids = [];
$priorities = [];
foreach ($unordered_array as $v) {
    [$ids[], $priorities[]] = explode('|', $v);
}
array_multisort($priorities, SORT_NUMERIC, $ids);
var_export($ids);
```